# Use the same InfoPath form for inserts and updates

Tags: infopath, external-content-type, external-list

I am using an InfoPath form to add records to a database table. I do this by creating an External Content Type in Sharepoint Designer. Then from the content type I create an External Sharepoint List.

I then click on the External Sharepoint List in Sharepoint Designer and can then generate an InfoPath form.

I am using Code with the form so I publish with Approval.

I just wanted to know since my proposed update form will look exactly like the insert form - is there a way to re-use the form as an UPDATE form ie, editifs.aspx

I attempted to do this by editing the editifs.aspx form in SP Designer and then manually in the markup pointed the infopath webpart to my previously created insert form.

I thought that if I passed (as a querystring parameter) in the bcdidentity that the form might be clever enough to display the existing record - yes... silly me!

Anyway, not sure how to do this. Also, the insert form has a View that is already set to "Edit Item". So even if I made a copy of it - I'm not sure how to hook it up to enable editing of existing items.

Any help appreciated.

thanks,
KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some experimenting I had to create a new InfoPath from from the existing External List template and then just changed the look and feel to match that of the insert form. All I do is pass in the bdcidentity to the editifs.aspx page in order to pull up the right record.

thx!
KS

Answer (score 1):

It is the same Infopath template that is OOTB and under the hood used on different ASPX webpart pages as pre-compiled webpart available upon publishing Infopath template.

Now, coming to guessing game.
You might find useful:

- The official blog of the Microsoft InfoPath team article [Using Multiple Views in Customized List Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/using-multiple-views-in-customized-list-forms)

As far as you use Infopath template of type/compatibility (what is most probable when you create it from SPD, OOTB it is impossible to use the same webpart for both inserting and updating. Even more, OOTB it is impossible to use different webparts (one for inserting and another for updating in the same ASPX Web Part Page, see my question:

- [How to change the type of infopath form received through "Get Form From" connection of web parts?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f6530c8-6dc8-486f-9815-e4faa00d0163/how-to-change-the-type-of-infopath-form-received-through-quotget-form-fromquot-connection-of-web?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Though, note here the words OOTB. Because it can be done:

- with the 3d party tools like [Qdabra Qrules](https://www.qdabra.com/en/products/qRules_new.aspx)
- with custom Infopath form template (created from Infopath but not OOTB from SPD or browser)
- using CAML

Though it is too broad topic for one (vague) question.
You should reformulate and repost more concrete question(s) about what really you are asking